# xmlCrypto.xpath is undefined after version upgrade from 'xml-crypto' 3.2.0 to 'xml-crypto' 4.1.0

Tags: javascript, express

After I upgrade 'xml-crypto' version 3.2.0 to 'xml-crypto' 4.1.0 in package.json, I start having `undefined` for `xpath`

```js
'use strict';
const xmlCrypto = require('xml-crypto');
const xpath = xmlCrypto.xpath;
```